# Dealing with nested lists from an api using jsonlite in R

Tags: r

I am pulling data into R from an api using fromJSON() and then using the flatten() from jsonlite. Why are some columns still nested lists?

```
teamstats <- fromJSON(getURL("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams?expand=team.stats"))

teamstatsflat <- flatten(teamstats$teams)

str(teamstatsflat)
```

Looking at the structure shows that $splits is still being treated as a list, and has not been unnested, but all of the other lists have been. I am pretty new to R so this may be a dumb question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `flatten` only allows you to flatten one level of your data, you can use `flatten(flatten(x))` to further flatten the list. But I guess what you may want is `?unlist` rather than `flatten`

Comment: the URL you provide returns 404 error, so I can't help to give an working example

Comment: I have updated the URL. I tried using flatten(flatten(x)), but that did not work. I will look into the unlist function. Thanks.

Comment: in your case, do `flatten(flatten(teamstats))`, it should return you something. Is that what you want? what's your expected output format?

Comment: ```flatten(flatten(teamstats))``` returns ```Error in flatten(teamstats) : is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE``` . I am looking to create a new data frame that has all of the variables from the underlying data in separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the data, you can actually extract most of the information without using `flatten`, try:

```
teamstats <- fromJSON("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams?expand=team.stats")

team <- teamstats[["teams"]]

team
```

If you do want the information in `teamStats` (the `splits` list) and put them into a dataframe, you can use the following code. The method needs `purrr` package to loop over all elements in the list:

```
library(purrr)
teamstats <- fromJSON("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams?expand=team.stats")
team2 <- teamstats[["teams"]]$teamStats
final <- map_df(team2,~as.data.frame(t(unlist(.x[["splits"]]))))
# you can ignore the warning information here

final
```